Is it safe to pass a uint32_t to a function which defines the input type as uint64_t?
Pass a uint32_t to a function that requires uint64_t: You can do this, and all compilers I know accept it, even in strict modes.

Is it explicitly allowed by the standard?
Is it safe?
What does MISRA-C say about this?

void MyFunction(uint64_t arg) {}

int main(void) {
    uint32_t xyz = 1u;
    MyFunction(xyz);
}


Yes it is safe and allowed by the C standard. The value of xyz will be promoted to uint64_t when it is copied into arg. However - I am not familiar with MISRA-C.

It isn't guaranteed to work, simply because uint32_t and uint64_t need not be supported on every implementation. But I suppose you are working under the assumption that they are supported.

I think MISRA recommends avoiding implicit promotions and using an explicit cast.

I just tested this using a well-known commercial lint tool for PCs with the MISRA-2012 ruleset and it does not complain about the implicit promotion.

@WeatherVane Re: "avoiding implicit promotions and using an explicit cast" --> IIRC widening is not an issue.

I posted an answer which actually explains why this is allowed by ISO C and MISRA C.


uintN_t types are in the C standard library C99 and later.

Optional types uint32_t and/or uint64_t might not exist, yet that is only on very unusual machines.  (E. g. CHAR_BIT == 9)

Code is missing #include <stdint.h>




Is it safe to pass a uint32_t to a function which defines the input type as uint64_t?

Yes.  Yet see above notes.

Is it explicitly allowed by the standard?

Yes.

Is it safe?

Yes.

What does MISRA-C say about this?

Type sign-ness and value changes are things MISRA and well enabled compilers whine about.
A sign-ness/value change does not occur in OP's code.

"Code is missing #include <inttypes.h>" More relevant, it is missing stdint.h. The inttypes.h is amount format specifiers etc to printf/scanf families - though it is guaranteed to include stdint.h. The thing is that an implementation does not have to support inttypes.h - an embedded systems compiler probably won't - whereas stdint.h is part of the minimum mandatory subset of the C standard lib which all compilers must support.

@lundin, Yes <stdint.h> is the better choice.

MISRA C:2012 nd MISRA C:2023 will both be OK with this, as long as the passed parameter is a simple expression (ie an object).
So, for example:
void fn( uint64_t param );
uint32_t object = 0U;
fn( object ); // Implicit promotion within unsigned integer is OK

If the passed parameter is a composite expression then Rule 10.7 and Rule 10.8 may be a consideration
void fn( uint64_t param );
uint32_t object1 = 0U;
uint32_t object2 = 1U;
fn( object1 + object2 );               // Rule 10.7 violated
fn( (uint64_t)( object1 + object2 ) ); // Rule 10.8 violated

See profile for affiliations

I believe you are mixing up rules 10.6 and 10.7. In this case 10.6 is what's relevant, 10.7 is about situations with composite expressions and "the usual arithmetic conversions" like u64 + (u32 + u32).


Is it explicitly allowed by the standard?

Yes.
The relevant parts of the standard are as follows:

During function call (C17 6.5.2.2) "...the
arguments are implicitly converted, as if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters". Meaning the rules for implicit conversion of function arguments to the stated parameters are the same as during assignment.

Among the allowed assignment constraints (C17 6.5.15.1) we find this valid form of implicit conversion:


the left operand has atomic, qualified, or unqualified arithmetic type, and the right has arithmetic type;


Meaning that during assignment, all integers signed/unsigned and all float types are implicitly converted to each other (which may or may not be a safe conversion).

Finally, the actual conversion rule applied in this case is simply this (C17 6.3.1.3):

When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.





Is it safe?

Yes.
When going to an unsigned type or a larger signed type anyway. Going from larger types to smaller signed types isn't necessarily safe since that invokes implementation-defined behavior and it could at least in theory result in an error state ("signal raised"). Going from floating point to integer types can also be problematic, particularly when going from signed float to unsigned integer.
Compilers and static analyzers often warn for "widening conversion during assignment". This can be avoided with an explicit cast. In case of narrowing conversions, one need to carefully inspect the code on case to case basis, as it might be a bug.


What does MISRA-C say about this?

The code as-is is MISRA compliant.
Chapter 10 of MISRA C:2023 about "essential type" (MISRA term) and conversions is what's relevant here. MISRA might assume that we know that function calls and assignment are equivalent here, as previously explained, so we have to check for rules about assignment.

The big essential type rule 10.1 doesn't apply to assignments/function calls.
10.3 forbids dangerous narrowing conversions of the kind I described previously.
10.5 allows explicit casts between unsigned types.
10.6 wouldn't allow code such as MyFunction(1u + 1u) since this is a so-called "composite expression" (MISRA term). The rationale is that the result of compound expressions might be unexpected due to implicit conversion, for example uint8a + uint8b results in a signed int.
10.7 and 10.8 have further requirements on composite expressions.


impressive answer quality - thanks!
